# jQuery Smooth Div Scroll with Colorbox

Tags: jquery, html, colorbox, smooth-scrolling

I found your jQuery Smooth Div Scroll tool online.  I'm planning to donate but I'm having trouble making it work with the colorbox option like you have on your site:
http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/colorbox.html

I'm a graphic artist and web designer looking for a gallery option to show my work. It seems that when I add the a href-tag that links to the large image it breaks the scrollable gallery.  I have a colorbox.css file linked in the head section of my html as:

```
<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/colorbox.css" />
```

I also have this in the body of the document:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
// Init Smooth Div Scroll   
$("#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll({
    mousewheelScrolling: "allDirections",
    manualContinuousScrolling: true
});

// Init colorbox
$("#makeMeScrollable a").colorbox({ speed: "500" });
```

});

Is there another piece to the puzzle that I am missing?  A javascript file?

This gallery would work perfectly.  Any help or advise you could give would be GREATLY appreciated!!

Thank you,

Gerry

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the jQuery library files and the colorbox script.

```
<!-- jQuery library - Please load it from Google API's -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- jQuery UI Widget and Effects Core (custom download)
     You can make your own at: http://jqueryui.com/download -->
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- Latest version of jQuery Mouse Wheel by Brandon Aaron
     You will find it here: http://brandonaaron.net/code/mousewheel/demos -->
<script src="js/jquery.mousewheel.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- jQuery Kinetic - for touch -->
<script src="js/jquery.kinetic.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- Smooth Div Scroll 1.3 minified-->
<script src="js/jquery.smoothdivscroll-1.3-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- If you want to look at the uncompressed version you find it at
     js/jquery.smoothDivScroll-1.3.js -->
<!-- Colorbox -->
<script src="js/jquery.colorbox-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you, I have added the library files and the colorbox script to the html The color box element is working perfectly but it seems to be breaking the scroll.  There is only the first image in the scroll gallery shown and when you try to use the scroll icons there is a flicker between the first and second images.

Comment: could it be possible that I have some conflicting scripts?

Comment: Here is the html page: http://www.gerardtonti.com/Scrollable%20Gallery%202/index.html

Answer (score 0):

[Colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox) include:

- jquery.colorbox.js
- colorbox.css
- images for loading, borders, close and etc

Comment: I have all of the above included.  The problem seems to be that adding the color box functionality breaks the scrollable gallery.  I'm getting only one image in the slide show and the scrolling functionality is gone.  Could I have conflicting scripts somewhere? Here is the HTML page:http://www.gerardtonti.com/Scrollable%20Gallery%202/index.html

Comment: @user1715071 You have next problems: 404 error for two pictures and invalid html-markup, from all you image links only first is closed, second is opened and other without `<a>` tag.